# Search for two consecutive rows with same data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a database of about 100 columns with similar data to from COL A to COL H.

I use the formula in COL J to search in a column for two consecutive rows with "-" and mark the second row as a double as you can see on J16 and J32.
This method is time consuming because I do often search for different columns and have to change the formula each time.

I would like something like N3. Entering the column ID and when I hit enter I will get automatically the count of rows with two consecutive "-" and also I would like to increase to search for triples and quadruples.

Any help will be appreciate.

Formula on J2:

```
=IF(AND(OR(F2=F1,F1="-"),F2="-"),"double","")
```

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmiSb.jpg)

Comment: Had an idea involving index, code and countifs (the latter with offset ranges) but there is simply no way I am going to retype your data.

Comment: Thanks. How can I upload an excel file here?

Comment: I think an excel formula might be too convoluted for this... could you use a macro instead? I think that'd be much easier, using data validation on N3 and having a `Worksheet_Change` event change the data in N5:N7

Comment: How can you have 100 columns between col A and col H? (I count máximum 8).

Comment: In your image I can see only up until half of column J, so the explanation is missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In N5 to count doubles,

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:H, 2, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64)), CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 3, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+1, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-")
```

This is the dynamic equivalent of using,

```
=COUNTIFS(G2:G20, "-", G3:G21, "-")
```

In N6 to count triples,

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:H, 2, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64)), CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 3, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+1, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 4, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+2, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-")
```

In N7 to count quads,

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:H, 2, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64)), CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 3, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+1, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 4, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+2, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-",
          INDEX(A:H, 5, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64):INDEX(A:H, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:H, , CODE(UPPER(N3))-64))+3, CODE(UPPER(N3))-64), "-")
```

If you require quints, you should be able to get the idea from those.

[image]

Comment: Right as I was typing that I thought an excel formula might be "too convoluted", you came with this! Of course!

Comment: Thank you guys. Both formulas works fantastic. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jeeped working with the actual data which is very large I found it would be better if the results for all columns are shown at the same time at the bottom so we can eliminate the enter box. I uploaded a revised image for this. Could you help me please.

Comment: @Jeeped the database goes to two letters columns, the above code only work with 1 letter columns.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use your column entry in cell N3. You can do this using the indirect function. Just change the formula in cell J2 **from** this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(F2=F1,F1="-"),F2="-"),"double","")
```

...**to** this:

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT(N$3&ROW())="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-1)="-"),"double","")
```

You can catch triples and quadruples in the same way, try this formula ...it'll only work from row 4 onwards, and the results may feel messy, depending on what you need:

```
=IF(AND(INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-1)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW())="-"),IF(AND(INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-2)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-1)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW())="-"),IF(AND(INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-3)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-2)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW()-1)="-",INDIRECT(N$3&ROW())="-"),"quadruple","triple"),"double"),"")
```

Comment: how can I put the results from all columns at the bottom like shown on the image? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the figure at the bottom, there are:

1. **Helper cells** `N1:N2` and `N9:N19`, whose contents helps the formulas you need being more concise.
   See below the explanation and formulas for these.
2. **Cells with the formulas you need**, using `SUMPRODUCT` combined with some form of dynamic referencing.

   1. Cells `N5:N7`
      give the result you want, but with fixed references. These are

       `N5`: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$21="-")*($G$3:$G$22="-"))`

       `N6`: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$20="-")*($G$3:$G$21="-")*($G$4:$G$22="-"))`

       `N7`: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$G$19="-")*($G$3:$G$20="-")*($G$4:$G$21="-")*($G$5:$G$22="-"))`

       You can grasp the systematics.
   2. Cells `O5:O7`
      give the same result, using `INDIRECT` instead of fixed references (**option #1 for what you need**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30983836/2707864)). These are

       `O5`: `=SUMPRODUCT(
      (INDIRECT($N$3&$N$9):INDIRECT($N$3&($N$10-1))="-")
      *(INDIRECT($N$3&($N$9+1)):INDIRECT($N$3&$N$10)="-")
      )`

       `O6`: `=SUMPRODUCT(
      (INDIRECT($N$3&$N$9):INDIRECT($N$3&($N$10-2))="-")
      *(INDIRECT($N$3&($N$9+1)):INDIRECT($N$3&($N$10-1))="-")
      *(INDIRECT($N$3&($N$9+2)):INDIRECT($N$3&$N$10)="-")
      )`

       You can grasp the systematics and write the formula for cell `O7`.
   3. Cells `P5:P7`
      give the same result, using `OFFSET` instead of fixed references (**option #2 for what you need**, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30983836/2707864), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800820/excel-formulas-for-converting-data-among-column-row-matrix/20800915#20800915), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912409/move-data-from-multiple-columns-into-single-row/30551048#30551048)). These are

       `P5`: `=SUMPRODUCT(
      (OFFSET($A$1,$N$12,$N$14):OFFSET($A$1,$N$13-1,$N$14)="-")
      *(OFFSET($A$1,$N$12+1,$N$14):OFFSET($A$1,$N$13,$N$14)="-")
      )`

       `P6`: `=SUMPRODUCT(
      (OFFSET($A$1,$N$12,$N$14):OFFSET($A$1,$N$13-2,$N$14)="-")
      *(OFFSET($A$1,$N$12+1,$N$14):OFFSET($A$1,$N$13-1,$N$14)="-")
      *(OFFSET($A$1,$N$12+2,$N$14):OFFSET($A$1,$N$13,$N$14)="-")
      )`

       You can grasp the systematics and write the formula for cell `P7`.
   4. There are likely other options combining `INDIRECT` and `OFFSET` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20544427/2707864)). An option using `INDEX` (although likely not the only variant) was covered by Jeeped.

---

Note on helper cells: 
I suggest having helper cells, and this applies to other answers posted here as well.
Of course you may move these cells around, adjusting the corresponding formulas.
The only non trivial formula here is for cell `N11`, `=COLUMN(INDIRECT($N$3&"1"))` (see [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3765-excel-convert-column-label-to-number.html) or [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-column-letter-to-number)).
Cell `N19` may be useful if you are going to use `INDEX`.

[image]