# Formula no working on 2 letters columns Excel

Tags: excel

Is there an easy way to modify the following formula to get it works on two letters columns? Thanks

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:Z, 2, CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64):INDEX(A:Z, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:Z, , CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64)), CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64), "-",
      INDEX(A:Z, 3, CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64):INDEX(A:Z, MATCH("zzz", INDEX(A:Z, , CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64))+1, CODE(UPPER(B5886))-64), "-")
```

Comment: Continuation of [Search for two consecutive rows with same data in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45600066/search-for-two-consecutive-rows-with-same-data-in-excel) with no original effort towards a resolution shown.

Comment: Recommended reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Jeeped I don't understand your meaning completely but I wont get response on the other post.

Comment: Function `OFFSET` is probably useful for you.

Comment: Without having your data, it is not easy to kow what you are trying to do.  But `=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(XES8),4),1,"")` can help you find the column letter (just change that `XES8` to the cell you are looking for).  Then you can use `INDIRECT` to apply the concatenate address.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed here is not a modification of the formula you showed, but I think it produces the result you are looking for (so it is technically "an easy way to modify the formula", by replacing it).

Try the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45669181/2707864) giving two options based on `SUMPRODUCT`/`INDIRECT` or `SUMPRODUCT`/`OFFSET`, which should work flawlessly also for columns having two-letter names.